# How to drag the mouse pointer to particular point and drop using sikuli webdriver?

Tags: sikuli

Currently, I am working on automating maps. I wanted to select the region using mouse pointer.

find region -> drag mouse pointer -> Drop.  Please suggest sikuli webdriver script for this.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of built in Sikuli functions: dragDrop() will encompass both the drag and the drop (like the name suggests) Or, you can do the steps separately, if needed (drag(), mouseMove(), dropAt()). These are all in the documentation [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html?highlight=dropat#Region.dragDrop).

I don't know much about webdriver or how it interacts with Sikuli, but hopefully its a starting place...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for enlarge a application window. I tested on both windows and linux OS and it work.

```
corner = find(Pattern('test.png' ).targetOffset(-36,-22))
drop_point = corner.getTarget().offset(dx, dy)
dragDrop(corner, drop_point)
```

The -36,-22 in function `targetOffset(-36,-22))` can be adjust by sikuli IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Here another example:

```
region1 = find("1429562753142.png")
dropRegion = Location(104,800)
dragDrop(region1, dropRegion)
keyUp()
```

I defined the reigion where the image is located. 
Then I defined the drop region. 
By using dragDrop() the image is moved. 
And keyUp() is releasing the keys that where being hold down.